# Matrix form of a simple formula

Tags: matrices

I have a dumb question. What is the best way of writing this equation in matrix/vector form?

$\sum_{i=0}^{L-1} A_i B_i C_i$

One option is $A_{1\times L} B_{L \times L} C_{L \times 1}$ where $B$ is a diagonal matrice.

Any ways to write it as a function of vectors $A_{L \times 1}$, $B_{L \times 1}$, and $C_{L \times 1}$?

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with the Hadamard product $\pmb{a}\circ\pmb{b}=\left(a_1 b_1,\cdots a_n b_n\right)$ then you could write your sum as, for example,
$$\left(\pmb{A}\circ\pmb{B}\right)\cdot\pmb{C}.$$